# Ant start background server process

Tags: ant

I'm trying to implement a simple Ant project who start a server in background mode in windows.
Here is my build.xml :

```
<project name="Test">
<target name="TargetTest">
<echo message="Starting Server"/>
<forget>
    <exec dir="C:\path\to\folder\" executable="C:\path\to\folder\executable.bat" spawn="true"/>
</forget>
<waitfor maxwait="5" maxwaitunit="minute" checkevery="10" checkeveryunit="second">
    <http url="localhost:port/applicationName"/>
</waitfor>
<echo message="Server started"/>
</target>
</project>
```

And i'm getting this error :

Problem: failed to create task or type forget
Cause: The name is undefined.

Action: Check the spelling.

Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.

Action: Check that any <"presetdef>/<"macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Thx for your help,

Comment: executing the same build xml with older version of ant got me this as answer : This is common and has a number of causes; the usual 
solutions are to read the manual pages then download and
install needed JAR files, or fix the build file

Answer (score 0):

It's about adding ant-contrib Jar file to Ant lib and declare the path this way :

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/usr/share/java/lib/ant-contrib-version.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```